# Default behaviour when starting up Intern tests with Selenium Tunnel

Tags: selenium, intern

I was just wondering if this was the default behaviour when starting up Intern with a Selenium Tunnel. At the moment, before running any tests, random pages that appear to look like the Intern-tutorial, which I used to learn how to run tests with Intern, seem to come up before attempting to run any of my own tests.

I have set up a vanilla install with no tests set up to demonstrate this behaviour. Please see the video link given below as reference if I have been unclear.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC15PbjSxVw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leadfoot, which is the WebDriver implementation used by Intern, performs feature and defect tests on the browser before testing starts. These tests tell intern about features that a particular browser might not support, or might implement incorrectly, giving Intern (well, Leadfoot) a chance to work around them.

Comment: Awesome, it's great to have confirmation. I appreciate the speedy response!